# MP3 tags from Amazon?

Tags: mp3, amazon-advertising-api

A lot of MP3 tagging tools (ex: http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) query Amazon to get tag data. How are they doing this, does amazon have an API for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out. They are just using the Product Advertising API (https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) and getting the info from a MP3 Downloads query.